# How to change a website default document programmatically on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Using ASP.NET 4.0, IIS 7.5.

I have a website engine, I have just implemented a way for this to tell if it's being loaded on mobile and instead of loading `Controls\MyControl.ascx` it loads `Mobile\Controls\MyControl.ascx`. This works well for my controls and also my `MasterPage.Master` file.

What I can't figure out however is how I can do the same with Default.aspx. This needs to be done on the fly programatically as I need to be able to check if it's mobile version. I was thinking of doing something on a pre-init event in globals but not sure if that's the best way.

Note: I don't want to use inline code on Default.aspx and just display different content base on my `Mobile` flag as my scenario goes one step further by basing the file on customer as well and this would mean having one huge Default.aspx for all customers which wouldn't be manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else looking at this I have found a solution but I am not sure I will implement it as I don't like the idea of updating the web.config file at run time. Using the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` namespace you can update the `server.webServer -> defaultDocument` section programmatically. Doing this allows you to change the path to default.aspx and it will load based on the variables you set.

This link should provide more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabh_singh/archive/2007/11/24/accessing-iis-7-0-features-programmatically-from-configuration-file-s-c.aspx

Also, the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` dll isn't available directly in VS so you need to add it from `%windir%\syswow64\inetsrv` (64bit version).

Answer (score 3):

Changing the default document on the fly is not possible in any **practical** sense.

Writing to the web.config on the fly to load a mobile version of a default page is quite frankly terrible and not an answer to the **true context of your issue**. I would feel irresponsible as a developer if I even proposed this as an answer to loading a mobile version of a default page.

I was trying to help you solve your problem and not just answer the base question in the title. As we all know, changing the web.config will restart your application and would not serve as a true solution, as you could not do this and achieve any kind of performance.

Here is the BEST alternative (IMHO) to dealing with mobile browsers.
http://51degrees.codeplex.com/

HTH!

Comment: It is my understanding that by the time I have hit `PreInit` on default.cs it is to late to change which default.aspx file is loaded. I cannot see how this helps.

Comment: All I can say is use 51 degrees or simply redirect if mobile or have the master choose a separate "mobile" contentplaceholder which can contain the usercontrols with the content you want (in separate files). HTH!

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question asked. I asked how to change the  default page loaded, not how to detect a mobile version and display different data as my engine already does that.

Comment: because you can't. why do think no one has answered it? I gave you three viable alternatives and you down vote? not cool....

Comment: Sorry Joe but if you restructure your answer to say it's not possible (although if you look at my answer, it is possible) and list the alternatives as alternatives, not solutions then I will retract my down vote.